# Why am I still getting 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'objects'?

Tags: python, django

After a few days of searching, I still am unable to get over this hurdle. I'm just trying to print a list of descriptions from Sellers as a view. Here's what I'm working with...

models.py:

```
from django.db import models


class Sellers(models.Model):
    index = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=False)
    seller = models.TextField(db_column='SELLER', blank=False, null=False,
                          primary_key=True)
    block = models.TextField(db_column='BLOCK', blank=False, null=False)  
    street = models.TextField(db_column='STREET', blank=False, null=False)  
    space = models.TextField(db_column='SPACE', blank=False, null=False) 
    description = models.TextField(db_column='DESCRIPTION', blank=True, null=True)
    document_with_idx = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False) 
    document_with_weights = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)


class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Sellers'


def __str__(self):
    return self.index
```

'''

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from search.models import Sellers


def search(request):
    output = Sellers.description.objects.all()
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

'''

Any direction would be appreciated, I feel like I've read every related post related to this. Figured it was about time to post a question with my exact setup. Thanks!

Comment: `Sellers.description` is an attribute, it is not a signle field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sellers.description` refers to the field, so you get basically the `TextField` object, not one of the `descriptions` of an object, since `Sellers` is a class, not a `Sellers` object. You can obtain the `description` values with:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from search.models import Sellers

def search(request):
    output = Sellers.objects.values_list('description', flat=True)
    return JsonResponse({'data': list(output)})
```

Furthermore you can not simply wrap that in a `HttpResponse`, since that expects a string/bytes-like object. You can for example JSON encode it with a `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I'm now getting the following error:

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /
Exception Value: relation "search_sellers" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "search_sellers"."DESCRIPTION" FROM "search_sellers"

Any idea why this pops up?

Comment: @nopaynenogain: did you make migrations and migrate the database. It looks like you did not yet let Django construct the tables at the database side. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/

Comment: Your new problem is a separate question, not a follow-up comment.  Please post it appropriately ... and remember to accept and/or upvote this answer.